# Express.js Session storage persistence issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, session, passport.js

I'm having a really odd issue with session storage using mongoDB and passport.

When a user logs in, the session is created and passed to mongo as expected as well as the passport id.

```
{
    "_id" : "GEEFIDhiMehdjPvtxRmPy_Kuls2IdVsx",
    "expires" : ISODate("2020-06-10T03:09:30.396Z"),
    "session" : "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":28800000,\"expires\":\"2020-06-10T03:09:29.358Z\",\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"passport\":{\"user\":\"ebf7d73d-f3f2-4f96-8123-3f0f262ffff6\"}}"
}
```

However, when the express server is restarted passport clears the user out of the sessions storage when a user selects a route that requires auth (there by invoking the isAuth function). Meaning users are required to login in after server restart.

```
{
    "_id" : "GEEFIDhiMehdjPvtxRmPy_Kuls2IdVsx",
    "expires" : ISODate("2020-06-10T03:11:54.464Z"),
    "session" : "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":28800000,\"expires\":\"2020-06-10T03:11:54.464Z\",\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"passport\":{}}"
}
```

My auth code is pretty standard stuff tbh, where am I going wrong here? I'm using the azure-ad passport strategy.

```js
const passport = require('passport');
const OIDCStrategy = require('passport-azure-ad').OIDCStrategy;
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
const config = require('../config');

const store = new MongoStore({
  url: config.databaseUri,
});

// Usual passport code here findbyoid, ensureAuthenticated etc

function setupPassport(app) {
  app.use(
    session({
      secret: 'somepassword',
      resave: true,
      cookie: {
        maxAge: 8 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
      },
      saveUninitialized: true,
      store: store,
    })
  );
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
}
```

Comment: Some things I would look for is ensuring that the session is in Mongo - meaning use some external tool to ensure the data is there. Then, if so, check again after restart. This may help narrow the issue. If your secret never changes (i.e. its not some crypto function to generate a secret) then I see no reason it would not fetch the session unless it never got there in the first place. Also testing things with a longer maxAge. Ive seen issues with server times being different causing weird expiration issues.

Comment: @cyberwombat the top 2 code snippets are from the mongo database bud, the sessions are defiantly stored, it just seems as if the sessions are never recollected after a restart and instead over written when the user logs in.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't actually storing the correct user information in the session or even looking in the session for the user information. Instead I was storing users in a local array and looking up their oid with deserializeUser function. the solution was to replace this with the code below.

```
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});
```

This way the user object was stored in the session database and then recollected when a user checked auth.